# Android Animation - Error: animation Fade In/Out works only when I scroll down

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments

I'm using the CollapsingToolbarLayout (with AppBarLayout and Toolbar) and with NestedScrollView (to the content of the Activity). I'm trying to animate the ImageView, that's allocated in the middle (between NestedScroll and AppBar, but above them) like the image below. The error: The effect Fade In works, when I scroll down, but when I try to scroll up, the effect (Fade Out) doesn't work, the ImageView only goes.

[image]

> SubscribeActivity

```
public class SubscribeActivity extends BaseActivity implements SubscribeMvpView {

    @BindView(R.id.nsv_subscribe)
    NestedScrollView nstScroll;

    @BindView(R.id.tlb_subscribe)
    Toolbar tbSubscribe;

    @BindView(R.id.imv_subscribe_avatar)
    CircularProfilePhoto ivProfilePhoto;

    @BindView(R.id.app_bar)
    AppBarLayout apl;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_subscribe);

        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        setUp();
    }

    @Override
    protected void setUp() {
        tbSubscribe.setTitle(R.string.str_subscribe_tlb);
        setSupportActionBar(tbSubscribe);

        ViewUtils.setStatusBarTranslucent(this, true);
        CommonUtils.showToolbar(this, R.id.tlb_subscribe, "", v -> finish());

        apl.addOnOffsetChangedListener((appBarLayout, verticalOffset) -> {
            if (verticalOffset <= -95 && verticalOffset >= -110 ) {
                ivProfilePhoto.animate().alpha(0).setDuration(300);
                ivProfilePhoto.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            } else if (verticalOffset >= -94) {
                ivProfilePhoto.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                ivProfilePhoto.animate().alpha(1).setDuration(300);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

> activity_subscribe

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:actionBarNavMode="standard">

    <!--HEADER-->
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/herocortado"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="@android:color/transparent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:statusBarScrim="@color/colorTransparent"
            app:titleEnabled="false"
            app:toolbarId="@id/tlb_subscribe">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/tlb_subscribe"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:navigationIcon="@drawable/back"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
                app:title=""
                app:titleTextColor="@color/colorWhite" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/nsv_subscribe"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            style="@style/stl_body"
            android:layout_marginTop="65dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edt_subscribe_nome"
                style="@style/stl_edt"
                android:hint="@string/str_subscribe_hint_edt_name"
                android:inputType="textPersonName" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvw_subscribe_name_error"
                style="@style/stl_msg_error_fields"
                android:text="" />

             <!— ANOTHERS FIELDS —>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <com.test.me.utils.CircularProfilePhoto
        android:id="@+id/imv_subscribe_avatar"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/defaultavatar" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like

```
ivProfilePhoto.animate().alpha(0.0f).setDuration(300).setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
            ivProfilePhoto.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    });
```

Comment: It does not works. The problem is still here. I tried to put this inside of the IF, and inside of the ELSE IF, but nothing.

Comment: @WallaceSilva Did you try debugging and see if it actually gets called?

Comment: Yes, to the both questions

Comment: The effect (Fade In) only works, when  I scroll down. The Fade Out, using the Alpha, does not work when I try to scroll up

Comment: Oh man, nice! It works! I inserted your method inside of the IF, with the Alpha 0.0f and the visibility VISIBLE! You saved me, thanks!

Comment: @WallaceSilva No problem, please accept my answer and up-vote it.

Comment: Ok! I'll do this now